# useFetch.ts hook react test mock

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-hooks, mocking, react-testing-library

There is a great typescript fetch hook I'd like to mock it.
Here: https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-fetch

My app basically looks like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const { data, error } = useFetch<InterfaceOfTheResponse>(FETCH_URL)

  if (error) return <p>Error</p>
  if (!data) return <p>Loading...</p>

  return (
    <div className="App">
       <h1>Welcome</h1>
       //data.map... etc
    </div>
  )
}
```

My test looks like this:

```
import { mockData } from "../__mocks__/useFetch"
const mockConfig = {
  data: mockData,
  error: false,
}

jest.mock("../../customHooks/useFetch", () => {
  return {
    useFetch: () => mockConfig
  }
})

describe("Main page functionality", () => {
  test("Renders main page, Welcome", async () => {
    const { findByText } = render(<App />)
    const WELCOME = await findByText(/Welcome/)
    expect(WELCOME).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

I've tried a couple of ways to mock it, this is the closest what I think it should work, but it's (obviously) not. It says, displays (in the test screen.debug()) the "Error" if statement, and even when I left out form the component the if error check, the "data" is undefined. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mock the implementation of the `useFetch` hook, you may break its functions. Instead, we should mock the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) API of the browser and its response.

E.g.

`App.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useFetch } from 'usehooks-ts'

const FETCH_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/api';
export default function App() {
  const { data, error } = useFetch<any[]>(FETCH_URL)
  console.log(data, error);

  if (error) return <p>Error</p>
  if (!data) return <p>Loading...</p>

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      {data.map(d => <div key={d}>{d}</div>)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

`App.test.tsx`:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import React from "react";
import App from './App';

describe('74144869', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const mData = [1, 2]
    const mResponse = {
      ok: true,
      json: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mData)
    }
    global.fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mResponse as unknown as Response);
    render(<App />);
    expect(await screen.findByText(1)).toBeInTheDocument();
  })
});
```

Test result:

```bash
PASS  stackoverflow/74144869/App.test.tsx (11.11 s)
  74144869
    ✓ should pass (58 ms)

  console.log
    undefined undefined

      at App (stackoverflow/74144869/App.tsx:7:11)

  console.log
    undefined undefined

      at App (stackoverflow/74144869/App.tsx:7:11)

  console.log
    [ 1, 2 ] undefined

      at App (stackoverflow/74144869/App.tsx:7:11)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   91.67 |       75 |     100 |     100 |                   
 App.tsx  |   91.67 |       75 |     100 |     100 | 9                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.797 s, estimated 12 s
```

package versions:

```json
"usehooks-ts": "^2.9.1",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
```

Comment: Oh all right... yes it is. :) Thank you so much.